# Use Up/Down keys to scroll a ListBox when a "gridview cell" has focus without moving cursor

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, listbox

i have a gridview control that a user can search in a particular cell and a corresponding ListBox which displays some results from DB. i want to do the following, Using the down and up keys, i want to scroll through the list box and when user press the enter key that selected list box value should append in gridview cell. I tried the following code, but the event doesn't fire up.

```
void dgvPOS_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            this.lbxProductName.Focus();
            this.lbxProductName.Select();

            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
            {
                this.lbxProductName.SelectedIndex--;
            }
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
            {
                this.lbxProductName.SelectedIndex++;
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I can only assume that the focus is not on the listbox. In that case the best method to catch the KeyUp, KeyDown and Enter is to handle it in the PreviewKeyDown event of the containing Form.

Answer (score 0):

### Another Soloution

If you are using WPF it contains the `System.Windows.Input` namespace with a class called Keyboard which allows for you to detect keystrokes system wide. More information can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboard(v=vs.110).aspx). Then with this you could check for keystrokes on the arrow keys, and with that you could change the `listBox.SelectedIndex` property to change current selections.

Have a nice day!